# How do I use Microsoft Graph to query all users in a specific Azure AD B2C subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

The question title really says it all. I cannot find this information in the docs.

My organization has several different subscriptions and active directory instances to keep users separate. I want to use the Graph API to query for all users in one specific AD B2C instance. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you done it? I also need to get all users however from the doc by creating "User Collection Page" I could get only 100 users...

Comment: No. Nothing about the way Microsoft's graph API or the documentation for it make any sense. I just gave up trying.

Comment: Hey I found a way. Check answers.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the trick...

In Azure b2c AD, users are stored "page" wise, one single page can store a maximum of 100 users and one API call - can present you a top/max of 999 users...but what if you have more than 999 users?

So here is how you can paginate users and get them in a List.

```
    List<List<User>> allUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    UserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    
    do {
        List<User> currentPageUser = users.getCurrentPage();
                    Collections.addAll(allUserList, currentPageUser);
                    UserCollectionRequestBuilder nextPage = users.getNextPage();
        users = nextPage == null ? null : nextPage.buildRequest().get();
    } while (users != null);
    
    return allUserList;
```

So once you have List of pages as List and each page will have 100 users...

So if you have 876 users, you will have 8 pages with first 7 pages with 100 users and 8th page with 76 users...

Answer (score 0):

You can always query all users in an Azure AD B2C tenant. You can use standard Microsoft Graph Apis for users.

Please see below page for users related operations in Azure AD B2C.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#user-management

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The docs just say use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`. That doesn't let me specify the subscription/B2C tenant / instance I want.

Comment: Please try calling the api, then only you will understand. In Microsoft graph, tenant is part of token. So whatever tenant you sign in, you will get these users

Comment: You need to explain "whatever tenant you sign in" because that's no explained anywhere in the docs.

Comment: A simple question to be on the same page AgmLauncher - have you ever called a Microsoft Graph api?

Answer (score 0):

To call Microsoft Graph, you need to use an access token for Microsoft Graph. See [Authentication and authorization basics for Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?context=graph/api/1.0) for details.

The access token includes a claim named `tid`, which

> Represents the Azure AD tenant that the user is from. For work and
> school accounts, the GUID is the immutable tenant ID of the
> organization that the user belongs to. For personal accounts, the
> value is 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad. The profile scope is
> required in order to receive this claim.

For how to get the access token, refer to [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph/api/1.0) and [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

You can see for both auth flow, you may need to call these 2 endpoints:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

You need to specify the `{tenant}` when you acquire the access token, then it will be included in the access token. For the use case of `{tenant}`, see details from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document).

After that, when you call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`, it will return you with the users from the specified tenant.